# Passing data from a $scope to another function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass data from $scope.abc() to an actual function.

[Function]

```
function sweetAlertCtrl($scope, SweetAlert, $state) {
    $scope.demo1 = function () {
        SweetAlert.swal({
            title: "Good job!",
            text: "You clicked the button!",
            type: "success"
        },
        function ($state) {
            $state.go('pjt.detailed', {id: $scope.id}) // This is where the data from $scope is received.
        });
    }
}
```

[Data from $scope]

```
$scope.demo1($scope.id);
```

How can I pass $scope.id to demo1() function?
Did I even put the $state in the correct location? I am new to this and this is really confusing :)

Please advise me what I should do.

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the $scope.id as a parameter to the function $scope.demo1:

```
$scope.demo1 = function (id) {
    SweetAlert.swal({
        title: "Good job!",
        text: "You clicked the button!",
        type: "success"
    },
    function ($state) {
        $state.go('pjt.detailed', {id: id})
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `$state` among the other dependencies in your `controller`/`service`/`factory`/etc, like this:

```
app.service('myService', function($scope, $state) {
    // Now you can use $state in all your functions here
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yes, you are right. I was missing that part. It was easy to make an action, but hard to find what the problem was. :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Providing a bit more code as answer is sometimes helpful ;)